# Combining jQuery scripts to make it smaller

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have written a jQuery script which does same task but on different events say

1. On page load
2. On change of dropdown selections
3. On click of swap button
4. On keyup in a text field

But I had to write the scripts for all of them separately. I am new to jQuery. I want to combine the scripts to work same but making it smaller. Is it possible?

Script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        // Fire this function when page loads
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $.getJSON(
                    'https://openexchangerates.org/api/latest.json?app_id=2e946db1e3fc4888b61330e505a804e5',
                    function(data){
                            if(typeof fx !== "undefined" && fx.rates){
                                    fx.rates = data.rates;
                                    fx.base = data.base;
                var amount = $("#amt").val();
                                    var from   = $("#from").val();
                                    var to     = $("#to").val();
                                    $("#res").val( fx(amount).from(from).to(to));
                                    $("#result").show();
                            }
                    }
            );
        });

        // Fire this function when value is entered in the field
        $(document).keyup('#amt', function(){
        $.getJSON(
            'https://openexchangerates.org/api/latest.json?app_id=2e946db1e3fc4888b61330e505a804e5',
            function(data){
                if(typeof fx !== "undefined" && fx.rates){
                    fx.rates = data.rates;
                    fx.base = data.base;
                    var amount = $("#amt").val();
                    var from   = $("#from").val();
                    var to     = $("#to").val();
                    $("#res").val( fx(amount).from(from).to(to));
                    $("#result").show();
                }
            }
        );
    });

        // Fire this function on swap button click
        $("#swap").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var fromVal = $("#from option:selected").val();
        var fromText = $("#from option:selected").text();
        var toVal = $("#to option:selected").val();
        var toText = $("#to option:selected").text();

        $("#from option:selected").val(toVal);
        $("#from option:selected").text(toText);
        $("#to option:selected").val(fromVal);
        $("#to option:selected").text(fromText);

            $.getJSON(
                    'https://openexchangerates.org/api/latest.json?app_id=2e946db1e3fc4888b61330e505a804e5',
                    function(data){
                            if(typeof fx !== "undefined" && fx.rates){
                                    fx.rates = data.rates;
                                    fx.base = data.base;
                var amount = $("#amt").val();
                                    var from   = $("#from").val();
                                    var to     = $("#to").val();
                                    $("#res").val( fx(amount).from(from).to(to));
                                    $("#result").show();
                            }
                    }
            );
        });

        // Fire this function on change of "FROM" dropdown selection
        $("#from").change(function () {
            $.getJSON(
                    'https://openexchangerates.org/api/latest.json?app_id=2e946db1e3fc4888b61330e505a804e5',
                    function(data){
                            if(typeof fx !== "undefined" && fx.rates){
                                    fx.rates = data.rates;
                                    fx.base = data.base;
                var amount = $("#amt").val();
                                    var from   = $("#from").val();
                                    var to     = $("#to").val();
                                    $("#res").val( fx(amount).from(from).to(to));
                                    $("#result").show();
                            }
                    }
            );
        });

        // Fire this function on change of "TO" dropdown selection
        $("#to").change(function () {
            $.getJSON(
                    'https://openexchangerates.org/api/latest.json?app_id=2e946db1e3fc4888b61330e505a804e5',
                    function(data){
                            if(typeof fx !== "undefined" && fx.rates){
                                    fx.rates = data.rates;
                                    fx.base = data.base;
                var amount = $("#amt").val();
                                    var from   = $("#from").val();
                                    var to     = $("#to").val();
                                    $("#res").val( fx(amount).from(from).to(to));
                                    $("#result").show();
                            }
                    }
            );
        });
</script>
```

Comment: You don'T want your API keys publicly visible. I suggest you remove them from the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's more like a general question, but here it is. You can reuse your code! Just put your code into a function like that.

```
function hello(){ console.log('hi!')}
```

And then you can pass it to another function

```
anotherFunction(hello)
```

Or simply call it

```
hello()
```

In your example you can do like this

```
function someFunction() {
    $.getJSON(
        'https://openexchangerates.org/api/latest.json?app_id=2e946db1e3fc4888b61330e505a804e5',
        function (data) {
            if (typeof fx !== "undefined" && fx.rates) {
                fx.rates = data.rates;
                fx.base = data.base;
                var amount = $("#amt").val();
                var from = $("#from").val();
                var to = $("#to").val();
                $("#res").val(fx(amount).from(from).to(to));
                $("#result").show();
            }
        }
    );
}
function passItToSwap(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var fromVal = $("#from option:selected").val();
    var fromText = $("#from option:selected").text();
    var toVal = $("#to option:selected").val();
    var toText = $("#to option:selected").text();

    $("#from option:selected").val(toVal);
    $("#from option:selected").text(toText);
    $("#to option:selected").val(fromVal);
    $("#to option:selected").text(fromText);

    someFunction();
}

$(document).ready(someFunction);
$(document).keyup('#amt', someFunction);
$("#swap").click(passItToSwap);
```

etc

Comment: Great.. Learned something perfect.. can you update your answer with how can I call swap function? I did `$("#swap").click(someFunction);` but it did not work

Comment: Just put a content of function passed to 'swap' function into another function and give it a name and then simply pass it to swap function by name. Try it, it's easy.

Answer (score 0):

You could divide the code in functions and create a separate file (`filename.js`) to include it in your HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You could reuse the same function for each handler, since you seem to have the same code in each of them:

```
var fx = {
        'base' : null,
        'rates' : true
    },
    getRates = function() {
        $.getJSON( 'https://openexchangerates.org/api/latest.json?app_id=2e946db1e3fc4888b61330e505a804e5', function(data) {
            var amount,
                from,
                to;
            if (typeof fx !== "undefined" && fx.rates) {
                fx.rates = data.rates;
                fx.base = data.base;
                amount = $("#amt").val();
                from = $("#from").val();
                to = $("#to").val();
                $("#res").val( fx(amount).from(from).to(to));
                $("#result").show();
            }
        });
    };
// Fire this function when page loads
$(document).ready(getRates);
// Fire this function when value is entered in the field
$(document).keyup('#amt', getRates);
// Fire this function on swap button click
$("#swap").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var fromVal = $("#from option:selected").val(),
        fromText = $("#from option:selected").text(),
        toVal = $("#to option:selected").val(),
        toText = $("#to option:selected").text();

    $("#from option:selected").val(toVal);
    $("#from option:selected").text(toText);
    $("#to option:selected").val(fromVal);
    $("#to option:selected").text(fromText);
    getRates();
});
// Fire this function on change of "FROM" and of "TO" dropdown selection
$("#from, #to").change(getRates);
```

Comment: Also, the `#from` and `#to` can be wrapped in the same selector. `$("#from, #to")`

Comment: I am not saying your code has any mistake but the form is not working... can u have a look again?

Comment: Your code didn't show where 'fx' is defined, so I had to guess. Add the part that creates the variable 'fx', so we can know how to handle it. Else just edit your own code to match a simialr structure ( aka use a variable to save the function you'll reuse. )